# R: order data frame according to one column

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
> bbT11
     range   X0  X1 total         BR      GDis      BDis         WOE         IV    Index
1   (1,23] 5718 194  5912 0.03281461 12.291488  8.009909  0.42822753 1.83348973 1.534535
2  (23,26] 5249 330  5579 0.05915039 11.283319 13.625103 -0.18858848 0.44163352 1.207544
3  (26,28] 3105 209  3314 0.06306578  6.674549  8.629232 -0.25685394 0.50206815 1.292856
4  (28,33] 6277 416  6693 0.06215449 13.493121 17.175888 -0.24132650 0.88874916 1.272937
5  (33,37] 4443 239  4682 0.05104656  9.550731  9.867878 -0.03266713 0.01036028 1.033207
6  (37,41] 4277 237  4514 0.05250332  9.193895  9.785301 -0.06234172 0.03686928 1.064326
7  (41,46] 4904 265  5169 0.05126717 10.541702 10.941371 -0.03721203 0.01487247 1.037913
8  (46,51] 4582 230  4812 0.04779717  9.849527  9.496284  0.03652287 0.01290145 1.037198
9  (51,57] 4039 197  4236 0.04650614  8.682287  8.133774  0.06526000 0.03579599 1.067437
10 (57,76] 3926 105  4031 0.02604813  8.439381  4.335260  0.66612734 2.73386708 1.946684
```

I need to add an additional column "Bin" that will show numbers from 1 to 10, depending on BR column being in descending order, so for example 10th row becomes first, then first row becomes second, etc.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you want to handle ties in case there can be any?

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward way is to use one of the `rank` functions from "dplyr" (eg: `dense_rank`, `min_rank`). Here, I've actually just used `rank` from base R. I've deleted some columns below just for presentation purposes.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% mutate(bin = rank(BR))
#      range   X0  X1 total         BR ...    Index bin
# 1   (1,23] 5718 194  5912 0.03281461 ... 1.534535   2
# 2  (23,26] 5249 330  5579 0.05915039 ... 1.207544   8
# 3  (26,28] 3105 209  3314 0.06306578 ... 1.292856  10
# 4  (28,33] 6277 416  6693 0.06215449 ... 1.272937   9
# 5  (33,37] 4443 239  4682 0.05104656 ... 1.033207   5
# 6  (37,41] 4277 237  4514 0.05250332 ... 1.064326   7
# 7  (41,46] 4904 265  5169 0.05126717 ... 1.037913   6
# 8  (46,51] 4582 230  4812 0.04779717 ... 1.037198   4
# 9  (51,57] 4039 197  4236 0.04650614 ... 1.067437   3
# 10 (57,76] 3926 105  4031 0.02604813 ... 1.946684   1
```

---

If you just want to reorder the rows, use `arrange` instead:

```
mydf %>% arrange(BR)
```

Comment: (+1) you could `arrange(desc(BR))` since they want it in descending order.

Comment: @beginneR, I thought about that, but their choice of words and the order they describe don't seem to match to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
bbT11$Bin[order(bbT11$BR)] <- 1:nrow(bbT11)
```